# Trying to get URL of page in extension but chrome.tabs.getSelected() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension and as part of this I need to get the URL of the visited page with this extension so to be able to manage it. But can't do this because this error: angular.min.js:117 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelected' of undefined

My manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Bookmark Manager Plugin",
    "description": "This extension will manage the users visiting history",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js": ["app/scripts/chrome.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Thumbnail Opener",
        "default_popup": "app/index.html",
        "default_icon": "app/favicon.ico"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["app/scripts/controllers/mainController.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

My popup html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="somename">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bookmarks Manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="components/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="components/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/chrome.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div style="margin-top:40px;"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                <form id=>
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <label for="input_1">Please Enter Keyword Pattern</label>
                        <input type="text" id="input_1" class="form-control" ng-model="inputValue"/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="hidd" name="url"/>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                <p ng-repeat="pattern in existingData">{{pattern.name}} - {{pattern.url}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My content_script file:

```
function getURL() {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        var myURL = tab.url;
    });
    return myURL;
}
```

My background js file:

```
angular
    .module('somename', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
        $scope.inputValue = getURL();
        $scope.showSuggestions = false;
        $scope.existingData = [{
                name: 'chrome extensions',
                url: 'https://www.sitepoint.com/create-chrome-extension-10-minutes-flat/'
            }, {
                name: 'yii',
                url: 'http://www.yiiframework.com/download/'
            }, {
                name: 'Jquery',
                url: 'https://jquery.com/'
            },
        ];
        $scope.searchDatabase = function() {
            $scope.existingData.forEach(function(el) {
                if (el.name.indexOf($scope.inputValue) > -1) {
                    $scope.showSuggestions = true;
                } else {
                    var url;
                }
            })
        };
    }]);
```

Can somebody help please, why chrome.tabs is not defined and how to make this work?

I tried this too:

in service file:

```
angular.module('somename').factory('getURL', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {

        promiseToHaveData: function () {

            return $http.get(chrome.tabs.query(null, function (tab) {

                return tab;
            })).then(function (tab) {

                var result = tab.url;

                return result;
            }, function (response) {

                console.log('Error has ocurred');
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

and in controller:

```
angular.module('somename', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'getURL', function ($scope, getURL) {

        getURL.promiseToHaveData().then(function (url) {

            $scope.inputValue = url;
        })
    }
```

but again not working - `angular.min.js:117 TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined`

Comment: First of all why first argument `chrome.tabs.query` is null? It is function takes object(can be empty {}) and callback.

Comment: Secondly i think you need use [deffered](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) object, because how i understand `http` used when need communicate with remote http servers. That is, you create a wrap function and inside it `chrome.tabs.query` result of that pass to `resolve` of this object. Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/06tG5EQ3). Then you calls wrap function and can use .then(). This [example](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/promises) emulate async function. Implementation promise in your code me seemed strange. Therefore i wrote second paragraph.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now

Comment: In [$http.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) first argument is string ( 
Relative or absolute URL specifying the destination of the request), you pass method of chrome.api. Second argument is optional and you no use it. You not correct use method

Comment: Yes you helped me with idea to use $q. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know `AngularJS`, but your code in `content_scripts` does not work because:

`content_scripts` does not have access to `chrome.api`.

> Here are some examples of what content scripts can do:
>
> - Find unlinked URLs in web pages and convert them into hyperlinks
> - Increase the font size to make text more legible
> - Find and process microformat data in the DOM
>
> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> - Use chrome.* APIs, with the exception of:
>
>   - extension ( getURL , inIncognitoContext , lastError , onRequest ,  sendRequest )
>   - i18n
>   - runtime ( connect , getManifest , getURL , id , onConnect ,    onMessage , sendMessage )
>   - storage
> - Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
> - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

```
$scope.inputValue=getURL();
```

And `background` does not have access to `content_scripts`.

You must transfer function in `background`.

[Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) | [Architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)

---

Your function does not return result, because `chrome.tabs.getSelected` is asynchronous, that is result will be returned (undefined), while `chrome.tabs.getSelected` is not finished executing.

Instead `return` you need perform actions in callback function.

[Asynchronous vs. synchronous methods](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#apis)

---

In addition `chrome.tabs.getSelected` is [deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected) since Chrome 33. You must use `chrome.tabs.query`:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){

    if(tabs.length != 0) {

        // Something
    }
});
```

The code returns active tab in current window.

[chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already read all of this documentation and because didn't find answer there decide to post my question here. So please if you have any idea explain it in more details. For example what to do instead of return in getURL()?

Comment: @LachezarB, you must transfer logic of work tabs to background scripts.
I don't know what you can do with `getURL` in context AngularJS.
You can try transfer `getURL` inside your angular module and perform following actions calls external method. See how chrome.api used in this example: [Todo Chrome Extension](https://angular-tutorial.quora.com/Make-a-Todo-Chrome-Extension-with-AngularJS-1).
Or if there is a possibility to transfer result of function to $scope from the outside.

Comment: May be I need a permissions as is written here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions

Comment: @LachezarB, for work with tabs need `tabs` permission. You already have it is in `manifest.json`. What did you do to solve the problem?

Comment: As I mentioned above I tried to use promise as an asynchr request but again the same: angular.min.js:117 TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Comment: @Lachezar, you moved `getURL` to `background` scripts?

Comment: yes I'm trying to get the API with promise asynchr.

Comment: @LachezarB, don't know what say. Need see code, which you change

Comment: It is in the question above I added new code below my question - "Can somebody help please, why chrome.tabs is not defined and how to make this work?"